# restrict user to enter 0 as the first character but allow 10 in the textbox

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I've a textbox on Windows Application where the user can enter only 3 digits in length and not allow only 0 but should be able to enter 10... The user should be able to do backspace delete.
I've the below code which restricts 0 even if entered 10.

```
 private void radtxt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
     if ((!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) 
                ||  (e.KeyChar == '.' || (e.KeyChar == '0'))
     {
         e.Handled = true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: You  should check only the first char of radtxt. But what about copy/paste?

Comment: Do not use the KeyPress event for input validation. The user can paste the value `0` through the context menu. Use a MaskedTextBox, don't reinvent the wheel. Also, read [ask] and try searching before asking a question.

Comment: I'll try MaskedTextBox

Comment: Do you really need to stop them entering leading zeros? Can you not just if they enter 010 just treat it as if they entered 10?

Comment: that's the business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check text box value every time, when user change it. Then, if value is equals zero change it as you want. 
On the other hand I advise you to read something about validation.